# Wordpress/PHP/JQuery Validation errors? HTML 5 validation fail?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a HTML form inside of a PHP file and I  am trying to validate this form using Jquery. To my dismay,I am not able to have the form validated before the page is summited, ie refreshed. Furthermore, I have use seveal different plugins and I do not get any notifications of any kind. Here is the form as is:

```
<div id="contactRight">
<form method="post" action="form.php">
<input type="text" class="required" id="first" value="First*" ></input><br/>
<input type="Last Name" value="Last*" id="lastname"></input><br/>
<input type="text" value="Email*" id="email"></input><br/>
<textarea id="subject" id="subject">Subject*</textarea>
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="submit"></input>
</form>
```

Using the bassistance validation plugin it says that you can give your inputs a class with a value of "required" causing the validation plugin to kick in. I am overfly frustrated with my attempts of making this form work. More so, using HTML 5 is catastrophic, I do not receice any notifications of any input fields not being filled in. Is there a different approach I should be taking?

Comment: Hahaha. Try to accept answers that will enhance the probability of getting answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use HTML5's native form validation, do the following:

1. for input fields requiring a value, add `required` attribute in the input tag
2. for checking email, the input tag should have a `type` attribute as 'email'.
3. for other sorts of pattern matching, use `pattern` attribute with regex.

Reference:
https://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2011/03/14/html5-form-validation-on-sumo/
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Blogs/Code/2012/11/21/creating-a-custom-html5-form-validation/

BTW, If you want to disable this native form validation, add `novalidate` attribute in form tag.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the problem, I can add a placeholder tag which will allow me to keep the values empty. I had values, so the validator was working as expected. Silly Me. My next question though, is the placeholder tag applicable in all other browsers?